# gdb remote returned an error e08

Tags: ios, oauth, gdb, remote-debugging

I am developing an iphone app that uses OAuth-Consumer library , my current debugger id LLDB
in that , it uses the following method to generate signauture

```
-(NSString *)signClearText:(NSString *)text withSecret:(NSString *)secret
{
 //it generates base64EncodedData and then returns it as a string
 return base64EncodedResult;//this is line is executed successfully

}//when it reaches this line it again goes to the return statement and there app      crashes
 //with the gdb error
```

If I use NSLog just before the return statement , it successfully prints the value of base64EncodeResult.

I tried a different debugger GDB, still the app crashes with the error 
"cannot access memory at location 0xYYYYYYY"

when I tried none debugger , then app does not crash but it stops executing further...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a buffer overrun on a local variable, it can foul up the stack frame.  If that happens you can overwrite the stack's return address so the app returns to an invalid address.

Comment: how to override stack's return address  ??